# recv continue without wait send

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I'm doing a client-server program with sockets but when I do recv from client and there is not a send by the server, the execution continues. I tried with the MSG_WAITALL flag but I have the same problem.
client:

```
ssize_t size_recv = recv(socketfd, buffer_rcv, RAW_MESSAGE_SIZE, MSG_WAITALL);
if(size_recv < 0 ){
    log_message(LOG_DEBUG, "Error");
}
else{
    printf("%zd Bytes recv\n", size_recv);
}
```

I get 0 bytes recv. How I do to block until send is executed?

Comment: `recv` returning 0 means the socket has been closed. Can we see more code leading up to the `recv`? The socket has definitely been connected at this point?

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why but I closed the socket in server, so i got 0 bytes.

Comment: It means the *connection* has been closed by the peer, which is what you did.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that on the server I had an instruction to close the socket, so the return was 0 bytes by this.